# "Река-красавица называют реку Волга". - синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксис

"Река-красавица называют реку Волга". 
Каким членом предложения является река-красавица?

Answer (score 2):

Река-красавица называют реку Волга. односоставное неопр.-личн. предложение с обобщ. значением.

Сказуемое НАЗЫВАЮТ РЕКА-КРАСАВИЦА

кого? что? реку -дополнение.

Какую?-Волга-определение, выраженное сущ., т.е. приложение.

Сказуемое составное именное со знаменательной связкой НАЗЫВАЮТ и осложняющим сущ.-приложением в именной части

Comment: И всё же предложение надо изменить.

Comment: Согласна, это разговорный вариант, но если нужно не править, а разобрать по членам предложения, нужно разобрать.